# Extract text from parent node and descendant nodes w/ xPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, extract, siblings

If I have these tags in an XML-file:

```
<a> Hello, I would like
   <b> to eat, please. </b>
</a>
```

or these (more complex):

```
<a> Hello, 
   <b class="A"> I would like</b>
   <b> to </b>
   <b/>
   eat, please.
</a>
```

, how would I do to extract the text from `a` and `b` so that the output would be:

```
Hello, I would like to eat, please.
```

I've gotten closest using `.//b[preceding-sibling::text()]`, but this gives me the text from one or the other, instead of combining them.

Don't know if it matters, but I'm doing this in python so the code would be `element.xpath('string(.//b[preceding-sibling::text()])')` using lxml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(/a)
```

will return the space-normalized [***string value***](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the `a` element,

```
Hello, I would like to eat, please.
```

as requested.

Comment: Thank you! I swapped /a with . (i.e. normalize-space(.)) which did the trick for me.